# Checks whether a DateTime belongs to the next day with respect to a reference DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

Given a reference DateTime and given a DateTime to be verified, how can I verify that the second date belongs to the next day (from midnight onwards)?

```
private bool IsTheNextDay(DateTime toBeVerified, DateTime referenceDate)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(referenceDate.Year, referenceDate.Month, referenceDate.Day);
    DateTime next = date.AddDays(1);
    return (toBeVerified >= next);
}
```

Using the above source code, it works.
Are there other better solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
private bool IsTheNextDay(DateTime toBeVerified, DateTime referenceDate)
{
    return referenceDate.Date.AddDays(1) == toBeVerified.Date;
}
```

The `Date` property simply uses 0 for the hourse/minutes/seconds/milliseconds components.

Comment: So if I want to know if the date has passed, I can write `if (toBeVerifiedDate.Date >= referenceDate.Date.AddDays(1))` or `if (toBeVerifiedDate.Date > referenceDate.Date)`

Comment: @enzom83 - Yes, if all you are interested in is the date.